# In MATLAB, how to create all the possible Sub-Matrices from a large Matrix by shifting exactly one row and one column?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, matlab-figure, submatrix

Suppose i have a 256*256 matrix(image pixel values).I want to create that Sliding window 1 to Sliding Window n by shifting exactly one row and one column. All the Sliding Window Matrix Should be in the size of 5*5.

I have tried with this following code. By this i am getting the submatrices but not by the shifting of exactly one row and one column.

```
I = imread('D:\Study Material\project\Finger Print Database\1_2.png');

J = imresize(I, [128 128]);

C=mat2tiles(J,[5,5]);
```

- Suppose original matrix has 10 row and 10 column.
- I'm getting the sub-matrices like (column1-column5 & row1-row5) then (column6-column10 & row6-row10).
- But I need like this- (column1-column5 & row1-row5)then (column2-column6 & row1-row5)like this first column will be shifted to 10. After that row will be shifted to 10.

Comment: I think the example of what you need is incorrect. Your second window has grown to `5x6` instead of `5x5`.

Comment: That's my mistake.It should be (column2-column6 & row1-row5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`im2col`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) with the `'sliding'` option, followed by [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html):

```
blockSize = [5 5];
C = reshape(im2col(J, blockSize, 'sliding'), blockSize(1), blockSize(2), []);
```

Comment: no,i'm not getting the actual one.i'm not getting the 5*5 matrix.

Comment: can we do it using for loop?

Comment: The result `C` is 3D array of size `5×5×n`. You can access each `5×5` matrix as `C(:,:,1)`, `C(:,:,2)`, ...

Comment: Okay.How can i use all this 5*5 matrix using a loop.Because i have to write a function which will work on the all 5*5 matrix.

Comment: `for k = 1:size(C,3); subMatrix = C(:,:,k); ...; end`

Comment: I have to write a function in which the value of all sub matrices will be changed using a formula.Then all the updated sub matrices will be saved.How can i write this function?

Comment: I’m not sure I follow. Anyway, that wasn’t in the original question